# On sharing a wordpress site in social media, it is showing coming soon but the site is live. Any suggestion?

Tags: wordpress

We are facing a different kind of issue with our wordpress site. On sharing the site url it is showing coming soon in preview. I am not sure what is going wrong here? Can anyone suggest please?[coming soon in preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtzXx.jpg)

Comment: Do you have some kind of maintenance mode plugin installed?

Comment: If you have SEO plugin, please check the values in that. May be you need to change the values there

Comment: I don't have any maintenance mode plugin installed but have SEO plugin installed.

Comment: We are using yoast seo but not sure where to make the changes... Khushboo can you please explain?